# Process of Java web application release

Tags: web-applications, memory-leaks, release-management, performance-testing, java-5

Trying to set up the process of releasing Java web applications in order to make sure that there are no memory leaks. It can involve making sure that the code written is of good quality, performance testing, profiling Java code. Would highly appreciate if anyone can share their process or anything that helps in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu), which is a tool specifically targeted at finding memory leaks and it doesn't have any GUI – if it finds the leak, it produces a Html report and says about it in the logs.

So, in your release procedure you can attach Plumbr to your application, run your set of automated tests and then monitor logs for the banner which says that there's a leak, if there's any. Another option is to use JMX to query Plumbr's status.